# Objective c/cocoa: How to write a proper multilanguage app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization, internationalization

Is there any way to easly manage the label and other text in the appliatcion for support multilang?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. You as the developer are going to be intimately involved with internationalizing every user-visible string and cultural assumption in your application.

The long answer is to read Apple's internationalization documentation, understand how resource look-up interacts with localization directories within the bundle structure, get familiar with `NSLocalizedString()` and its relatives, and play around with some `.strings` files and changing your system language around in order to get a feel for how what you're doing will affect the end-user.

When it comes to localizing information contained in XIBs, you should read Wil Shipley's article ["Lost in Translations."](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html) You might also want to look at how open source Cocoa projects such as Growl and Adium handle internationalization and localization.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Apple's [Introduction to Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html) is best suited for your needs. I would recommend checking out both "Preparing your nib files for localisation" and "Localising string resources" on that page as they are most frequently used in multi-language apps. Make sure you know how they could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple answer, just read their tutorial (as you should always do when digging into a new aspect of Apple developing):

http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/